# no gitignore file in new rails app

Tags: git, rails

I created a new Rails app using version 3.0.1 (in order to follow along with a tutorial using 3.0.1), but it didn't create a gitignore file. If I create my own, what ending should I put on the file? is it an rb file? or can you explain why it might not have created this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't a ruby file. It is simply a list of files or directories to ignore. Simply create a file called `.gitignore`. There is no extension.

Comment: but rails creates the file automaticall

Comment: What are you talking about? You just said *"but it didn't create a gitignore file"*

Answer (score 3):

`.gitignore` is a file used by [Git version control system](http://git-scm.com/). It has nothing to do with Ruby and you don't need to create it unless your project uses Git as a version control system. Here is more info about gitignore if you are interested: http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/19/ignoring-files.html

Answer (score 2):

Michael, I thought I had this issue too; maybe rails is creating the file, but it is just hidden.  Make sure you are seeing all the hidden files; on Ubuntu, when the folder where your other rails folders appeared, enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to toggle files being hidden/unhidden.

Comment: This is true. `.gitignore` is a dotfile, therefor hidden by the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

I am new for Ruby on Rails. I did not have .gitignore file because is hidden. To open it on your text editor go to root dir  and type .gitignore and will come out on your text editor.Good luck

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` is not a ruby file. But you can make it visible in the rails root application by `touch .gitignore` command.